# Suppress static code inspection in R (future package)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, future, static-code-analysis

I have a long calculation which I am trying to parallelize using future package (specifically within an R shiny application).

I have used dplyr package for all data manipulations and there are a lot of column names that are not referred with quotation marks. When I try to run this function that I know to be working when non parallelized, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in : Identified global objects via static code inspection ({if (i > maxProgress) {; maxProgress <- i; shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb",; value = 100 * i/length(scanList)); ...; }; return(resultInstance); }). Failed to locate global object in the relevant environments: ‘Months in Service’
```

because static code inspection thinks ‘Months in Service’ is a global variable and fails to find it (it is in fact a column name of a dplyr tibble), so it never runs my code.

If  I do the following globally before calling the function:

```
`Months in Service` <- NULL
```

it gives the same error for another column name. So one solution is to define each of those names as global variables and hope dplyr will work the same. However is there another simple way to get around this such as telling R to evaluate everything as it would have done without parallelization (each iteration is completely independent)

Edit 1: I simplified the operation and tested if NULL would actually work. It doesnt, it would complain because it thinks column name is NULL, for example:

```
no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Edit 2: example reproduction

```
 library("dplyr")
 library("listenv")

  exampleTibb <- tibble(`col 1`=c(1,2,3))
  exampleFuture <- listenv()
  exampleFuture[[1]] %<-% future({ rename(exampleTibb, `col 2` = `col 1`) })
  exampleFuture <- as.list(exampleFuture)
```

Comment: Easier to help if you create a stripped down example that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: @atiretoo Just added one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package here: This is due to a [bug](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/globals/issues/35) that has been fixed for future 1.8.0. I'm preparing to submit this to CRAN, but in the meanwhile you can either do:

```
options(future.globals.onMissing = "ignore")
```

or, better, install the [develop](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/tree/develop) version:

```
remotes::install_github("HenrikBengtsson/future@develop")
```

UPDATE 2018-04-08: future 1.8.0 is now on CRAN.

---

UPDATE 2018-04-07: This error only occurs when using *nested* futures.  Note that you introduce nested futures by mistake when you use both `%<-%` and `future()`.  That is a clearly a mistake.  You want to use, either:

```
exampleFuture[[1]] %<-% { rename(exampleTibb, `col 2` = `col 1`) }
```

or

```
exampleFuture[[1]] <- future({ rename(exampleTibb, `col 2` = `col 1`) })
```

and certainly not both.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for. could you also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712010/appending-a-global-table-using-asynchronous-futures-in-r

Comment: Note that you're using futures incorrectly; see the UPDATE section in my answer above.